# Classic ASP Request.Form some times does not return any value on post

Tags: forms, asp-classic, request

I have a classic asp page. 
this page redirecting another asp page using by post method.

But the page redirected gets no value from Request.Form collection at one in a while.

We are logging HTTP erros in a table.
When i check the log i've found out one thing in common. The browsers are mostly Mozilla.

Some similar browser details below;

```
Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Mozilla/4.05 [en] (WinXP; I)
Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; tr) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.546 Mobile Safari/534.8+
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/3.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/3.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Ezooms/1.0; ezooms.bot@gmail.com)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MJ12bot/v1.4.3; http://www.majestic12.co.uk/bot.php?+)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; BOIE9;TRTR)
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_5 like Mac OS X; tr-tr) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8L1 Safari/6533.18.5
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A406 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A403 Safari/8536.25
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; tr-tr) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_5 like Mac OS X; tr-tr) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8L1 Safari/6533.18.5
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; tr-tr; HTC_Wildfire_A3333 Build/FRG83D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/534.57.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.29700/28.1857; U; tr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; tr) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.11
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; tr) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00
TurnitinBot/2.1 (http://www.turnitin.com/robot/crawlerinfo.html)
Windows-Live-Social-Object-Extractor-Engine/1.0
```

I've tried many times in difrent browsers and OS. But i've just represent same situation at once but i can't catch anything. One more log in table.

What should i do for that?

I did not user classic asp before. Also Trying debug problems are another challenge to me.

Thanks in advance

The posted form as below

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="redirect.asp">
      <table width="511" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>Aracın Markası</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="markaoto" class="list1">
              <%
            set markalar=conn.execute("select * from dbtable ORDER BY field")
            do while not markalar.eof
            %>
              <option value="<%=markalar("idfield")%>"><%=markalar("field")%></option>
              <%
            markalar.movenext
            loop
            %>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>Kullanım Tipi</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="tarz" class="list1">
              <option value="0" selecteud="selected">Tümü</option>
              <option value="1" >Hususi</option>
              <option value="2" >Hafif Ticari</option>
              <option value="3" >Ağır Ticari</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>Şehir</strong></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11"><strong>:</strong></td>
          <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="iloto" class="list1">
              <%
            set iller=conn.execute("SELECT * FROM TBL_ILLER ORDER BY IL")
            do while not iller.eof
            if iller("ILKOD")=34 then
            %>
              <option selected="selected" value="<%=iller("ILKOD")%>"><%=iller("IL")%></option>
              <% else %>
              <option value="<%=iller("ILKOD")%>"><%=iller("IL")%></option>
              <%
            end if
            iller.movenext
            loop
            %>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td width="103" height="30" align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="19" align="left" valign="middle" class="icerik_txt_11">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="389" height="30" align="left" valign="middle"><a href="#" onclick="anlasmalioto();" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image5','','images/index/ara_hl.gif',1)"><br />
            <img src="images/index/ara.gif" name="Image5" width="85" height="23" border="0" id="Image5" /></a>
            <div id="Waiting" style="visibility:hidden">Lütfen Bekleyiniz</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
```

The redirected page server side code which gets the posted form value as below;

```
            <%
        Dim regEx
        Set regEx = New RegExp
        regEx.Global = true
        regEx.Pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z]"
                marka=regEx.Replace(Request.Form("markaoto"), "")
        tarz=regEx.Replace(Request.Form("tarz"), "")
        il=regEx.Replace(Request.Form("iloto"), "")

        On Error Resume Next
            set marka_ad_al=conn.execute("select * from servisListMarka_V2 where markaId = "&marka)
            marka_ad=marka_ad_al("marka")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            conn.execute("insert into ErrorLogTable(CodeRowNumber,LogPage,LogString)values(103 , 'anlasmali_cam_servisleri2.asp' , 'marka=" & marka & " / tarz=" & tarz & " / il=" & il & "')")
        else
            set marka_ad_al=conn.execute("select * from servisListMarka_V2 where markaId = "&marka)
            marka_ad=marka_ad_al("marka")
        end if
        set il_ad_al=conn.execute("SELECT * FROM TBL_ILLER WHERE ILKOD="&il)
        il_ad=il_ad_al("IL")
                If tarz = "0" Then

                sql = "WITH L AS(SELECT ST.SERVICE_TYPE_ID,S.*,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(BRAND, ',','</M><M>')+ '</M>' AS XML) AS BRAND_ID FROM SERVICE S INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES ST ON S.SERVICE_ID = ST.SERVICE_ID where S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 and ST.SERVICE_TYPE_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND S.STATUS = 1 AND S.CITY_ID = "& il &") SELECT L.*, SPLIT.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS BRAND_ID FROM L CROSS APPLY BRAND_ID.nodes('/M') SPLIT(A) WHERE SPLIT.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')='" & marka & "' ORDER BY SERVICE_TYPE_ID asc,EHOM DESC , ASU DESC"

            'sql = "SELECT * FROM SERVICE WHERE (BRAND LIKE '%," & marka & "%' OR BRAND LIKE '%" & marka & ",%' OR BRAND = '" & marka & "') AND CITY_ID = "& il &" AND SERVICE_TYPE = 1 AND STATUS = 1 AND IS_ACTIVE = 1 ORDER BY EHOM DESC , ASU DESC"

        Else

            'sql = "SELECT * FROM SERVICE WHERE (BRAND LIKE '%," & marka & "%' OR BRAND LIKE '%" & marka & ",%' OR BRAND = '" & marka & "') AND CITY_ID = "& il &" AND USAGE_STYLE LIKE '%,"& tarz &",%' AND STATUS = 1 AND IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND SERVICE_TYPE = 1 ORDER BY EHOM DESC , ASU DESC"

            sql="WITH L AS(SELECT ST.SERVICE_TYPE_ID,S.*,CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(BRAND, ',','</M><M>')+ '</M>' AS XML) AS BRAND_ID FROM SERVICE S INNER JOIN SERVICE_TYPES ST ON S.SERVICE_ID = ST.SERVICE_ID where S.IS_ACTIVE = 1 and ST.SERVICE_TYPE_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND S.STATUS = 1 AND S.CITY_ID = "& il &" AND USAGE_STYLE LIKE '%"& tarz &"%') SELECT L.*, SPLIT.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS BRAND_ID FROM L CROSS APPLY BRAND_ID.nodes('/M') SPLIT(A) WHERE SPLIT.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')='" & marka & "' ORDER BY SERVICE_TYPE_ID asc,EHOM DESC , ASU DESC"

        End If

        sql_uk = sql

        set bul=conn180.execute(sql)
        If Not bul.eof then
        %>
```

Here is the javascript code which is posting the form below;

```
function anlasmalioto(){

btn = document.getElementById("Image5");
btn.style.visibility = "hidden";

waiting = document.getElementById("Waiting");
waiting.style.visibility = "visible";

document.form1.submit();
```

}

Comment: What triggers your form post? I don't see a submit button so I'm guessing it's the _anlasmalioto();_ javascript function? Is that correct? How does it trigger the form submit exactly ? Just with _document.form1.submit();_ or does it alter the action? Looking at the code, it's possible that you just didn't select any option and thus don't have anything in your form to post... have you tried making a specific selection and then submitting?

Comment: Yes you're right the javascript you called anlasmalioto is posting the form. I'll edit my post to add js function